# how to get 6 pack abs in 1.5 month

Tags: exercise, diet, gym, abdominals

This is about my body:

5'9 height
60Kg (~130lb)
don't have much fat on tummy

Schedule:

wakeup
work
work
eat
work
work
workout
eat
sleep

diet: vegetarian

made a bet with friend and need 6 pack abs in 1.5 month

I followed some youtube tutorials to do abs and crunches, don't see any effect

I need a fool proof way to achieve this

Comment: Do squats, deadlifts, and high intensity interval training.

Comment: Body fat is the key here imho, about 8%. Calorific deficit and planks. No evidence to back that up im afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visible abs are achievable in this time. Question is, how much are you willing to sacrifice / give away to reach this goal?

Apply intensive [insert any diet name] diet.

Apply any specific training program designed to decrease overall body fat.

Get tempted and buy fat burners.

Quick gains achieved by following magic supplements / super diets / training regimes usually do not last for very long and for a good reason. Body itself won't allow them to inflict this kind of damage to their bodies over extend period of time. At some point it will burn out one way or another (read: injury/ get ill / losing motivation, inspiration and etc).

It might be fun trying something out and you can even catch the bug! But to achieve long standing results the 'time' variable might go out from the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Abs are made in the kitchen.

You can do like Serge Nubret, 2000 crunchs per day, but if you have a poor/unbalanced diet, they'll never appear.

You have to review your diet.

You can visit [bobybuilding.com](http://www.bodybuilding.com/) for some example, tips etc for fat loss/shred.

Answer (score 0):

The smart money is on your friend and here's why. "Six pack abs" are a result of hard work, genetics, dedication, consistency, diet and smart training. See where I'm going with this?  Like any other body part it takes time to sculpt it. So, unless you're predisposed to great abs, your chances are pretty slim given the time frame and the fact there's no "fool proof" method to achieve them.